# Meteor validated method not found

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm migrating my Meteor application from Meteor 1.2 to Meteor 1.3 and following the guide on http://guide.meteor.com/methods.html#validated-method to create a validated method.

When I call the method, I believe client-side simulation is happening, as I can log out to console, but this is always followed by the error `Method '...' not found`.

**/imports/ui/pages/register.js**

```
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
import {Template} from 'meteor/templating';
import {FlowRouter} from 'meteor/kadira:flow-router';

// Methods
import {createAccount} from '/imports/api/accounts/methods.js';

// HTML
import './register.html';

Template.Register_page.events({
  'submit form': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var user = {
      email: $('#email').val(),
      password: $('#password').val(),
      profile: {
        firstName: $('#firstName').val(),
        lastName: $('#lastName').val()
      }
    };

    createAccount.call(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        console.log('User successfully registered');
        FlowRouter.go('Dashboard');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

**/imports/api/accounts/methods.js**

```
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
import {ValidatedMethod} from 'meteor/mdg:validated-method';
import {SimpleSchema} from 'meteor/aldeed:simple-schema';
import {Accounts} from 'meteor/accounts-base';

export const createAccount = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'createAccount',
  validate: new SimpleSchema({
    email: { type: String },
    password: { type: String },
    profile: { type: Object },
    "profile.firstName": { type: String },
    "profile.lastName": { type: String }
  }).validator(),
  run(user) {
    console.log(user);
    Accounts.createUser(user);
  },
});
```

**Client console**

```
Object {email: "test@mailinator.com", password: "testPassw0rd", profile: Object}    methods.js:18
errorClass {error: 404, reason: "Method 'createAccount' not found", details: undefined, message: "Method 'createAccount' not found [404]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"}    register.js:28
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the reason this wasn't working was because I was not initialising the javascript on the server at startup.

Adding the following fixed the issue:

**/imports/startup/server/index.js**

```
import './register-api.js';
```

**/imports/startup/server/register-api.js**

```
import '/imports/api/accounts/methods.js';
```